# identifying a time period spent in a place that is longer than expected by chance

Tags: stopping-times

I have an object that moves randomly back and forth across a line (L) with frequency of movement (F) and speed (S) dependent on temperature (T), and temperature raising at a rate(r). I would like to know whether the object is staying within a tract (tr=L/10; i.e. a tenth part of the line's length) during more time than expected by the length of the tract and speed of the object given its temperature. Is this possible?

If speed is length/time, I think it could be put in terms of the experiment's line, tract length with respect to line`s length, and of the rate of temperature rise. Then, extract the expected t for the given length of the tract, at any given temperature. That should allow to identify a maximum time spent per line's tract that can be expected by chance. However, I lack the skills to do that math reliably. I can offer coauthorship on an article in exchange for this help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is not completely clear to me. Is the object in an oscillatory movement (with some amplitude and frequency dependent on T), or is it in a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. It moves randomly back and forth, like in a random walk.

Comment: And what depends on the temperature? (the step size of the walk, I guess)?

Comment: the speed depends on temperature, so if each step is assumed to be instantaneous, yes, the step length.

Comment: but remember that the frequency of movement also depends on temperature, as originally stated in the problem.

Comment: As long as we have a model of the dynamics of the object, computing the likelihood of time spent per tract should be fine. Do you have a document with a description of the problem? I will add an institutional email to my bio.

Comment: Else, I ask what do you mean by frequency of movement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136191/discussion-between-g-frazao-and-agus-camacho).